# count the number of occurrences using in a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a df that looks something like this (5m rows and around 250 different treaty numbers (both as strings)):

```
      Id   Name    Treaty Number
 0  Id88   Jack              x12
 1  Id87   John              x33
 2  Id88    Jim              x22
 3  Id11   Hans              x12
 4  Id12   Ivan              x33
 5  Id88   Sara              x22
 6  Id11    Max              x12
 7  Id11  Peter              x33
```

I would like to find all the duplicate IDs and the count of every treaty number belonging to the id.

Perfectly, It would look like this:

```
           Sum  
   Id88      3    x12: 1, x22:2, ....
   Id11      3    x12: 2, x33:1,...
```

Right now I have following code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    data = np.array([
    ['Id88', 'Jack', 'x12'], 
    ['Id87', 'John', 'x33'], 
    ['Id88', 'Jim', 'x22'],
    ['Id11', 'Hans', 'x12'],
    ['Id12', 'Ivan', 'x33'],
    ['Id88', 'Sara', 'x22'],
    ['Id11', 'Max', 'x12'],
    ['Id11', 'Peter', 'x33'],
    ])
    columns=['Id', 'Name', 'Treaty Number']

    df = pd.DataFrame(data= data, columns = columns)

    dublicateIDs = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Id'],keep=False )]

    pivotIDs = dublicateIDs.pivot_table(index=['Id'], aggfunc='size')
    pivotIDs = pivotIDs.sort_values(ascending=False)

    pivotTreaty = dublicateIDs.pivot_table(index=['Id'], columns = 'Treaty Number', aggfunc='size', 
    fill_value=0)

    concatDF = [pivotIDs, pivotTreaty]
    pivotIDsCombine = pd.concat(concatDF, axis=1, sort=False)
    columnNames = pivotIDsCombine.columns.tolist()
    columnNames[0] = 'Sum'
    pivotIDsCombine.columns = columnNames
    print(pivotIDsCombine)
```

And following result:

```
         Sum  x12  x22  x33
 Id88      3    1    2    0
 Id11      3    2    0    1
```

Because of the large number of rows (5m) and treaty numbers (250) and only the small number of treaties for every ID, I have a huge table full with NaNs (or zeros).

Is there a easy way using a pivot table to reach the desired format or should I go loop ever every column/row and count the number of occurrences manually?

Comment: Would you be ok with a dictionary, or you need a dataframe as output?

Comment: A dict would be also okey, I would prefer to have a df because so I can easily save it as a  csv

Comment: You can easily have the pivot table with this:
`pd.pivot_table(df, index='Id', columns='Treaty Number', aggfunc='count')` It needs some more work for the column of duplicates. Do you want me to work on it? The result hoever will be similar with the one above (one column per x.. Number)

Comment: I can easily remove the duplicates and use the pivot_table statement you wrote me. My question is how to left only the Treaty Numbers who have values different than 0(NaN) like this: Id11      3    x12: 2, x33:1,...

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out

```
df['temp'] = 1
df1 = df.groupby(['Id', 'Treaty Number'])['temp'].count().reset_index()
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='Treaty Number')
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
df1.columns.name = None
df1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df1['Sum'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: actually, it is not. It gives me similar result to the one I already have. What I want is a result in this form:
                Sum  
       Id88      3    x12: 1, x22:2, ....
       Id11      3    x12: 2, x33:1,...